# Rails - update records before destroying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, updates, destroy, belongs-to

I have a rails app managing customer records, customer records belong to a status and there is a 'status' table defining the various statuses.

I would like users to have the option to destroy statuses.  However, customer records may refer to the status being destroyed.  Can I do the following. When a user requests to destroy a status, there is a form with the destroy action which allows the user to choose a status to be destroyed and then forces them to choose a different, existing status that all the records with that status are to be updated to.  The customer records are then updated and the status is then destroyed.

If this is possible please could you point me in the direction of a tutorial or give me an explanation of how to do it.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

How about rendering a "chose new status" form before you destroy the previous status and you save the record? If you show some code one could guide you to a direction as well.

Comment: Thank you for replying,  haven't posted code as currently it pretty much looks like default rails code.  Status controller and customer records controller.  Customer records belong to status.  Trying to work out the logic to force an update to the customer record status before I delete a status